# CS231n assignment 2: TwoLayerNet and Solver

Tags: numpy, neural-network

I'm running into an error message when I try to execute solver.train.

I finished editing fc_net, including initialization, feed-forward, loss and backward propagation. When I executed the FullyConnectedNets code that meant to compare their solution vs mine, everything went fine (my analytic gradients identical to the numeric ones, same loss, etc.) dimensions are also the same (otherwize the comparison would have not worked).

Nevertheless, when I try to execute the solver I'm running into an error message. Specifically, I execute these lines:

```
model = TwoLayerNet()

solver = Solver(model, data,

update_rule='sgd',

optim_config={

'learning_rate': 1e-3,

},

lr_decay=0.95,

num_epochs=10, batch_size=100,

print_every=100)

solver.train()
```

And the error message I get originaly comes from `optim.py` and it says:

```
41 config.setdefault('learning_rate', 1e-2)

42

---> 43 w -= config['learning_rate'] * dw

44 return w, config

45 ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (100,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (100,100)
```

Did someone get similar error? From the message I understand that the gradient and W are not of the same dimensions. How could it be if all the test up to this part were positive?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you defined the function `affine_backward` under the layers.py file, you set

```
db = np.sum(... keepdims=True)
```

You need it to be just

```
np.sum(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `db = np.ones((1, dout.shape[0])) @ dout` in the `affine_backward` and also got your error. After changing the line into `db = dout.T @ np.ones(N)`, the error is gone.